# Google cloud logging, using python with docker container

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have simple python app and want to use google cloud logging. I use docker and run it with kubernetes.

How can i send the logs to google cloud logging?

```
import time
import logging

def main():
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    try:
        while True:
            logging.info('Working...')
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info('Stopped working')
        pass;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it, I updated the question thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure your logger to write to stdout, Kubernetes will automatically send it to Google Cloud Logging for you.

Otherwise you'll have to use a sidecar container to collect the logs and upload them for you, like in [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/logging/fluentd-sidecar-gcp).

Comment: Link broken; does [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/logging.md) look like what you were referring to?

Comment: Not quite -- this is: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/logging/fluentd-sidecar-gcp